# running service in background above 4.2 versions

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which is running correctly in jellybean 4.1 below versions.

I'm getting problem in running service in background for android 4.2 above versions.please help in solving this problem.

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AutoResponseLog");
     File log = new File(dir, "AlarmLog.txt");

      BufferedWriter out;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(
                                new FileWriter(log.getAbsolutePath(),
                                                log.exists()));
        out.write(new Date().toString());
          out.write("\n");
          out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     Context c = getApplicationContext();
     SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

     String er = app_preferences.getString("set", "done");
    if(er.equals("done"))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "registering the recever", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        Uri mediaUri = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        CustomContentObserver custObser = new CustomContentObserver(handler);
      getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(mediaUri, false, custObser);

    }
      return START_STICKY;
  }
```

Comment: did you get any error ?please show logcat error.

Comment: Please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "problem in running service in background" you are seeing.

Comment: I'm not getting exactly what happening,it runs correct in 4.1 version but it is not running in 4,2

Comment: getting problem in OnReceive function.